# translate event in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here I am drawing a rectangle in highcharts by selection event ,i am getting the the co-ordinates of the box by translating the axis values of the chart i:e

`chart.xAxis[0].translate((event.xAxis[0]||chart.xAxis[0]).min)`

. My question is how can I get the reverse of this, i:e

`event.xAxis[0].translate((event.xAxis[0]||chart.xAxis[0]).min)`.

I have attached the fiddle below , please see to it for better understanding of my question, Thanks in advance.
[Js-Fiddle containing above question's code.](https://jsfiddle.net/gopalravi/wqnq8jfd/2/)

Comment: can you be more specific about what you mean by "the reverse" - what values do you want, and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Please see to the fiddle , there i am getting the x and y values by the above syntax. next i am planning to resize the box that is drawn by selection, Can I get the x position and y position by the same method i got for drawing the box???  i haven't included the code, but if i do can i get the xMin,yMin,xMax,yMax (see to fiddle) ??  @jlbriggs

Comment: @Gopal It seems that what you are looking for are coordinates in pixels from axis scale. If yes, then there is API frunction for that - API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels If not, then maybe further explaining of what are you planing to do could help?

Comment: @kacper madej: thank you very much, it worked .thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you are looking for are coordinates in pixels from axis scale. If yes, then there is API function for that - [Axis.toPixels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels).

> **toPixels** *(Number value, [Boolean paneCoordinates])*
>
> Translates a value in terms of axis units in to pixels within the chart.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> ***value:*** *Number* A value in terms of axis units.
>
> ***paneCoordinates:*** *Boolean*
>   Whether to return the pixel coordinate relative to the chart or just
>   the axis/pane itself.
>
> **Returns:** *Number*